# How can I dynamically set the directory for media field in admin

Tags: form-fields-types, media-manager

I've got 2 directories on my root:

```
/images/ <-- with user's images
/media/  <-- with system ( and components ) images
```

The global parameter for image root is set to `media` but I want to decide via the field where to find my image.

The XML for the admin form is

```
<field
    id="contest_image"
    name="contest_image"
    type="NewMedia"
    required="false"
    imgroot="images"
    directory=""
    label="Contest_image"
    description="contest_image_Desc"
    preview="true"
    exclude="" 
    stripext="0" />
```

I've duplicated the original field in NewMedia for avoiding confusion and set this one with:

```
if ($this->value && file_exists(JPATH_ROOT . '/' . $this->value))
{
    $folder = $this->imgroot . '/'.$this->directory;
}
elseif (file_exists(JPATH_ROOT . '/' . $this->imgroot . '/' . $this->directory))
{
    $folder = $this->imgroot . '/'.$this->directory;
}
else
{
    //$folder = '';
    $folder = $this->imgroot ;
}
```

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

In your Model, you have to override `getForm` method to set values dynamically. Make sure you are extending your Model with either JModelForm or JModelAdmin. Once done, try following code:

```
public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true)
{
    $form = $this->loadForm('com_yourcomponent.yourformname', 'yourformname', array('control' => 'jform', 'load_data' => $loadData));

    if (empty($form))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (condition)
    {
        $form->setFieldAttribute('contest_image', 'directory', 'Your Value if condition is true');
    }
    else
    {
        $form->setFieldAttribute('contest_image', 'directory', 'Your Value is false');
    }

    return $form;
}
```